# After piping a file with SQL statements to mysql, how can I keep the command line session open?

Tags: mysql

A file, in.sql, contains a CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE statement followed by some INSERTs that populate the above table. Temporary tables are purged after the session closes, so 'mysql -u user -p pass < in.sql' has no net effect once the mysql process is done with in.sql and terminates. I would like to keep the session open to continue working on the temporary table interactively. Does such an option exist? 
(A simple workaround, of course, would be to create a non-temporary table and drop it when I'm done with it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start an interactive shell, then just do:

```
source in.sql
```

... at the mysql prompt. The session will still be open after the file is executed, unless the file has a command in it that causes the mysql shell to exit.